# fast data comparison in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

I want to compare a large set of data in the form of 2 dictionaries of varying lengths.
 (edit)

```
post = {0: [0.96180319786071777, 0.37529754638671875], 
        10: [0.20612385869026184, 0.17849941551685333],
        20: [0.20612400770187378, 0.17510984838008881],...}

pre = {0: [0.96180319786071777, 0.37529754638671875],
       1: [0.20612385869026184, 0.17849941551685333],
       2: [0.20612400770187378, 0.17510984838008881],
       5065: [0.80861318111419678, 0.76381617784500122],...}
```

The answer we need to get is 5065: [0.80861318111419678, 0.76381617784500122]. This is based on the fact that we are only comparing the values and not the indices at all.

I am using this key value pair only to remember the sequence of data. The data type can be replaced with a list/set if need be. I need to find out the key:value (index and value) pairs of the elements that are not in common to the dictionaries.

The code that I am using is very simple..

```
new = {}
found = []

for i in range(0, len(post)): 
    found= []
    for j in range(0, len(pre)): 
        if post[i] not in pre.values():
            if post[i] not in new:
                new[i] = post[i]
                found.append(j)             
                break
    if found:
        for f in found: pre.pop(f)
```

new{} contains the elements I need.
The problem I am facing is that this process is too slow. It takes sometimes over an hour to process. The data can be much larger at times. I need it to be faster.

Is there an efficient way of doing what I am trying to achieve ? I would like it if we dont depend on external packages apart from those bundled with python 2.5 (64 bit) unless absolutely necessary.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically what `set`s are designed for (computing differences in sets of items). The only gotcha is that the things you put into a `set` need to be hashable, and `list`s aren't. However, `tuple`s are, so if you convert to that, you can put those into a set:

```
post_set = set(tuple(x) for x in post.itervalues())
pre_set = set(tuple(x) for x in pre.itervalues())

items_in_only_one_set = post_set ^ pre_set
```

For more about `set`s: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

To get the original indices after you've computed the differences, what you'd probably want is to generate reverse lookup tables:

```
post_indices = dict((tuple(v),k) for k,v in post.iteritems())
pre_indices = dict((tuple(v),k) for k,v in pre.iteritems())
```

Then you can just take a given tuple and look up its index via the dictionaries:

```
index = post_indices.get(a_tuple, pre_indices.get(a_tuple))
```

Comment: That looks like a reasonable solution.

Comment: That looks good, but the OP said that they need the key:value pairs. Your solution loses the keys.

Comment: I need the index numbers corresponding to the values. When it gets converted to a set from dict, I think the numbers get jumbled up.

Comment: @sbetharia - what you probably want to do then is construct a reverse-lookup dictionary that maps tuples to indices. [Example added to answer.]

Comment: There are a few problems: If there are duplicate values the reverse lookup will fail - that may seem unlikely for floats, but common values like `0.0` or `1.0` can be problematic. It also has no respect for the indices, when `pre = { 0 : tup_a, 1 : tup_b}` and `post = { 0 : tup_b, 1 : tup_a}` it would regard them equal. *If* these problems have to be solved it can be done with 3-tuples like `(a,b,index)` or a custom object with `__hash__` and `__eq__`.

Comment: @JochenRitzel - considering the OP's question deals with comparing the non-shared contents of the sets without regard to the indices, that would seem to indicate that the values which would be looked up are both (a) unique, and (b) only in a single set.

Comment: I think I like the idea of using a reverse look up dict. But all in all, wont it hamper the overall speed ? Say, when I have to do that for thousands of values?

Comment: @sbetharia - it's more efficient than what you're doing, because generating the reverse-lookup dicts is O(N+M), whereas what you're doing is O(N*M) or worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely the nested `for` loops combined with use of `range()`, which creates a new `list` each time which can be slow. You will probably get some automatic speedups by iterating `pre` and `post` directly, and avoid doing so in a nested fashion.

```
post = {0: [0.96180319786071777, 0.37529754638671875],
       10: [0.20612385869026184, 0.17849941551685333],
       20: [0.20612400770187378, 0.17510984838008881]}

pre = {0: [0.96180319786071777, 0.37529754638671875],
       1: [0.20612385869026184, 0.17849941551685333],
       2: [0.20612400770187378, 0.17510984838008881],
    5065: [0.80861318111419678, 0.76381617784500122]}

'''Create sets of values, independent of dict key for O(1) lookup'''
post_set=set(map(tuple, post.values()))
pre_set=set(map(tuple, pre.values()))

'''Iterate through each structure only once, filtering items that are found in
   the sets we created earlier, updating new_diff'''
from itertools import ifilterfalse

new_diff=dict(ifilterfalse(lambda x: tuple(x[1]) in pre_set, post.items()))
new_diff.update(ifilterfalse(lambda x: tuple(x[1]) in post_set, pre.items()))
```

`new_diff` is now a `dict` such that each value is not found in both `post` and `pre`, with the original index preserved.

```
>>> print new_diff
{5065: [0.80861318111419678, 0.76381617784500122]}
```

Comment: set(post.items())
# Error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: In my case the dict a = dict(a=['A','B'], b=['C','D']) and I need to compare only the values of the 2 dicts. Your example gives me this error: set(post.items())
# Error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that earlier. I've updated my answer to compensate.

Comment: I am not sure if the index numbers are getting in the comparison as well. We only need to compare the values, not the index numbers. I will update my example in the question.

Comment: when we convert to (key, tuple(value)) the index number gets in the comparison too, correct ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your post specifically says "I need to find out the key:value (index and value) pairs of the elements that are not in common to the dictionaries."